# MongoDB: How to query all subdocuments of a collection

Tags: mongodb

I have the collection `users`, and each of the user objects have a field called `purchases` which is an array of objects.  The user object looks as follows:

```
User:
{
    ...
    purchases: [
        { time: 2355645366, amount: 2000 },
        { time: 2456456334, amount: 2000 },
        { time: 2435645433, amount: 2000 },
    ]
}
```

How do I query for all purchases among all users, as well as sort by fields such as `time`?  The result I would expect would be an array of purchase objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregations operations, a very handy tool for scenarios like this

```
db.users.aggregate({$unwind: '$purchases'},{$sort: {'purchases.time': 1}},{$group: {_id: 0, 'purchases': {$push: '$purchases'}}})
```

the returned document will have the following structure :

```
{ "_id" : 0, "purchases" : [...all users purchases sorted by time here...]}
```

Comment: Will test out and report back in a bit

Comment: *5 years later*

Some say he's testing out to this day.